# Dynamically change value on href according to URL with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to dynamically change a value on a `href` according to the url. So for e.g I have the url: `testing.this.com?id=54908765`, I'd want to change all the links to have the same id value on the end i.e. `this.url.com?id=54908765`.

Is this possible just by using JavaScript? I couldn't find any obvious solution when googling. 
Thanks.

Comment: You should start with [document.getElementsByTagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName)

Answer (score 0):

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var spslid = getParameterByName('id');
function change()
{
var z =  $("a") ;

for(int i=0; i<z.Count ; i ++)
{

z[i].attr("href" , z[i] +spslid);

}
}

change();
```

This is a approach